# Rejected edit reason

Tags: discussion

I made this edit: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/45690, which was rejected - by a two to one margin.  Both rejections using the "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

The reason for rejecting doesn't make sense to me -- the edit was made **after** a discussion in comments with the author, and nothing I added in any way addresses the author. Basically it fixes a couple of mistakes in the code so that it is actually runnable.

Are these rejections off base or is this a community standard that I am unaware of? Should I not be editting others code?

Answer (score 3):

Generally editing others code is only done to format, like if they weren't aware of the code formatting tool. Revisions to code typically come from the author stemming from comments or chat. If you feel the answer is wrong, either bring it to the authors attention or post the correct code as your own answer.

Comment: I don't think the answer is "wrong", it has a typo ("l" instead if "i"), which keeps it from executing and is missing a return which prevents it from working as designed.  But if the reject reason had been "don't edit his code, let him do it himself" I wouldn't have asked the question.  If you are going to reject an edit because it changes the code, shouldn't that be the reason for rejection and not "don't chat via edits".